# How to parse id number before calling find element by id using python selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome

I'm trying to automate linkedin connection request using python selenium but problem is every time the value of ember number keeps changing.
when I try to copy id of button It gives certain string one time //*[@id="ember418"] and other time it gives //*[@id="ember502"] so the number keeps changing
is there a way to find this number before passing id value??

this is the complete element tree I'm working on

```
<div data-test-modal="" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="artdeco-modal artdeco-modal--layer-default send-invite" size="medium" aria-labelledby="send-invite-modal">
        <span class="a11y-text">Dialog content start.</span>
        <button data-test-modal-close-btn="" aria-label="Dismiss" id="ember414" class="artdeco-modal__dismiss artdeco-button artdeco-button--circle artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view">  <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="cancel-icon" class="artdeco-button__icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M13.42 12L20 18.58 18.58 20 12 13.42 5.42 20 4 18.58 10.58 12 4 5.42 5.42 4 12 10.58 18.58 4 20 5.42z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>

<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    
</span></button>
        
      <div id="ember415" class="artdeco-modal__header ember-view">
        <h2 id="send-invite-modal">
            Your invitation is almost on its way
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="ember416" class="artdeco-modal__content ember-view">
<!----><!---->
            <p class="display-flex">
                <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="success-pebble-icon" class="connect-button-send-invite__success-icon mr1" size="large"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M12 2a10 10 0 1010 10A10 10 0 0012 2zm-1.25 15L7 13.25l1.41-1.41L10.59 14l4.84-6H18z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
                <span class="flex-1">
                  You can add a note to personalize your invitation to <strong>Zoe Yang</strong>.
                </span>
            </p>
<!---->
      </div>
      <div id="ember417" class="artdeco-modal__actionbar text-align-right ember-view">
          <button aria-label="Add a note" id="ember418" class="mr1 artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--3 artdeco-button--secondary ember-view"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Add a note
</span></button>
        <button aria-label="Send now" id="ember419" class="ml1 artdeco-button artdeco-button--3 artdeco-button--primary ember-view"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Send
</span></button>
      </div>
      
        <span class="a11y-text">Dialog content end.</span>
      </div>
```

I'm trying to click add a note and send buttons by finding the id

when I call

```
connect = more = driver.find_element_by_id("""ember418""").click()
```

it will click that button

but problem is every time it get refreshed or reclicked ember number keeps changing

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
> element: {"method":"id","selector":"ember524"}   (Session info:
> chrome=90.0.4430.93)

so I want to fetch this ember number before finding the element by id

is there a way to achieve this? any help will be grateful

Comment: What exactly linkedIn site page are you are working on?

Comment: i'm logging in to linkedin first then I'm loading specific profile page to whom should I send connection request. I'm adding note before sending connection . this is my goal

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `xpath` to select that element:
`//button[contains(@class,'primary') and contains(@class,'profile-actions--connect')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath .//button[@aria-label='Add a note']